# How to remove column headings on returned data when making T-SQL calls from within VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am using VBA to output information into an Excel worksheet that has been gathered from a SQL Server database called "PHB". I can connect to the database and pull information by calling a view.

When I dump the data into my Excel worksheet the column headings of the database data are included and I don't want that. I have to use an offset to get the data to look right. I can manipulate the results worksheet and remove the columns with VBA. If there is some switch I can use on either (VBA or T-SQL) end it seems like it would be a much cleaner and simpler approach.

Here are the relevant parts of my logic:

```vb
Public Sub Show_ProductCode()
    
    Dim PHB_cnn                             As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim ProductCode_qry                     As String
    Dim ProductCode_rst                     As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ProductCode_qtbl                    As QueryTable
    Dim ProductCode                         As String
    Dim OffsetAmt                           As String
    Dim OffsetAmt_int                       As Integer
    
    PHB_cnn.Provider = "sqloledb"
    PHB_cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    PHB_cnn.Open p_PHB_Connect_s           'In Module
            .
            .
            .
    For Each c In DataRange_rng
        ProductCode = c.Value
    
        ProductCode_qry = "SELECT * FROM vw_ShowPurchaseHistory WHERE ProductCode = '" & ProductCode & "'"
            
        ProductCode_rst.Open ProductCode_qry, PHB_cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
            
        With ProductCode_rst
            OffsetAmt = .RecordCount
            If ProductCode_rst.EOF Then
                Debug.Print "No Records"
            Else
                OffsetAmt_int = OffsetAmt_int + (CInt(OffsetAmt) * 2)
                With Worksheets("Results")
                    Set ProductCodes_qtbl = .QueryTables.Add(ProductCode_rst, .Range("A" & OffsetAmt_int))
                    ProductCodes_qtbl.Refresh
                End With
            End If
                
        End With
    
        If ProductCode_rst.State = adStateOpen Then ProductCode_rst.Close
        Set ProductCode_rst = Nothing
    
        Set ProductCode_qtbl = Nothing
            
    Next c
    
exit_Show_ProductCode:
    
    If ProductCode_rst.State = adStateOpen Then ProductCode_rst.Close
    Set ProductCode_rst = Nothing
    
    Set ProductCode_qtbl = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
        
err_Show_ProductCode:
    
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly
        
    Resume exit_Show_ProductCode
        
End Sub
```

My input data:
[image]

My output:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with [Range.CopyFromRecordset method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) This should copy only the datarange, excluding headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is going to be very inefficient as it is executing a SQL statement for each ProductCode. It would be better to loop through these values and build up a SQL IN statement and then, after the loop, execute it once e.g.

```
...
ProductCode_in = "('productcode1', 'productcode2','productcode3',...., 'productcode_n')"

ProductCode_qry = "SELECT * FROM vw_ShowPurchaseHistory WHERE ProductCode IN '" & ProductCode_in
...
```

You'll then end up with all your data in Excel with a single header row - which is simple to delete with a VBA statement (sheet.row(1).delete).

Comment: Thank you NickW!  I had forgotten about the T-SQL "IN" functionality.  I have used it before but it has been quite a while since I did.  I changed my code to include it and the results came in just as you said.  No multiple headers and I don't even need to remove the header at the top.  And it is fast.  Thank you again for the great suggestion.